# How would look a harmonic and p-harmonic series vector in a multidimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, intuition, harmonic-numbers

Learning about the [harmonic series](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) divergence and p-harmonics series convergence, I tried to manipulate them globally as follows.
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}A \cdot I = \lim_{n \to \infty}
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{1} & \frac{1}{2} & ... & \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{1^2} & \frac{1}{2^2} & ... & \frac{1}{n^2} \\
... & ... & ... & ... \\
\frac{1}{1^n} & \frac{1}{2^n} & ...& \frac{1}{n^n} \\
\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ ... \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n} \\ \sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^2} \\ ... \\
\sum_1^\infty\frac{1}{n^n} \\ \end{pmatrix}= v
$$
Where $A$ is the matrix of the harmonic and p-harmonic series, $I$ is the identity matrix and $v$ would be a vector of an infinite dimensional space.

One of the interesting things of this composition is that the trace of $A$ is curiously (please correct me if this is wrong) the [Sophomore's Dream identity](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream). And it is equivalent to the sum of the eigenvalues of the matrix.

$$tr(A)= \sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^n} = \int_0^1 x^{-x} dx = \sum_i \lambda_i$$

I would like to ask the following questions:

> 1. Are the matrix and vector operations correctly defined as I wrote them?
> 2. Topologically, how would look $v$ in that multidimensional space? initially all the dimensions converge to a number, because they depend of the p-harmonic series, but the dimension that depends on the harmonic-series does not converge.
> 3. The trace is also convergent, but $v$ is not totally convergent to a point (meaning it is not a point in that multidimensional space due to the dimension that depends on the harmonic series). Is that compatible?
> 4. In the other hand, in the case of the transpose matrix, $A^T\cdot I =v'$, if I am not wrong $v'$ would be totally convergent to a point in all its dimensions, so it would really be a point in the multidimensional space, is that intuition right? Thank you!